# Finding probability using nested for loops in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, probability, nested-loops

My problem is that whenever I try to compile and run my program, it says one of my arithmetic problems closer to the end of my code is dividing by zero. Now there is another problem. Whenever the user is prompted to enter the number of rolls, you can input a number and hit enter, but it just skips to the next line and nothing happens. Nothing else in the code happens.

*** NOTE ***

I can't use arrays in this assignment because it is not covered until the next section.

Here is my assignment [here](https://access.desire2learn.com/content/enforced/33909-5312_OFF_13_017.001/educator_apcsa_v9/module05/rtfmod05/5.05_AssignmentInstructionsDiceProbability.pdf?_&d2lSessionVal=gtu91phg7xjofH089eMdDdTc6). This is what i'm supposed to be doing. I can't figure out what is going wrong here. My math seems to be correct but something is going wrong.

In short my assignment wants me to find the probability of two 11 sided dice being "rolled" the amount of times the user inputs. For example:

If the user says the dice it to be rolled 100 times it would output it something like this
2s:          (insert Probability of having the sum of the 2 dice being 2 after 100 rolls)
3s:          (insert Probability of having the sum of the 2 dice being 3 after 100 rolls)
4s:          (insert Probability of having the sum of the 2 dice being 4 after 100 rolls)
5s:          (insert Probability of having the sum of the 2 dice being 5 after 100 rolls)

and so on.

Here is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{

    //Declare and initialize variables and objects

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random randNum = new Random();




    int match = 0; //Number of times sum of dice matches the current sum

    int die1 = 0; //Random generated numbers
    int die2 = 0;
    int diceTotal2 = 0;
    int diceTotal3 = 0;
    int diceTotal4 = 0;
    int diceTotal5 = 0;
    int diceTotal6 = 0;
    int diceTotal7 = 0;
    int diceTotal8 = 0;
    int diceTotal9 = 0;
    int diceTotal10 = 0;
    int diceTotal11 = 0;
    int diceTotal12 = 0;

    int sumOfDice = 0;
    double probability2 = 0.0;
    double probability3 = 0.0;
    double probability4 = 0.0;
    double probability5 = 0.0;
    double probability6 = 0.0;
    double probability7 = 0.0;
    double probability8 = 0.0;
    double probability9 = 0.0;
    double probability10 = 0.0;
    double probability11 = 0.0;
    double probability12 = 0.0;


    //Input: ask user for number of rolls and number of sides on a die

    System.out.println("Number of Rolls: ");

    int rolls = in.nextInt();

    //***************************************************************************************

    //Using nested loops, cycle through the possible sums of the dice.

    //Roll the dice the given number of times for each sum.

    //Count how many times the sum of the dice match the current sum being looked for.

    //***************************************************************************************


    //Loop to increment through the possible sums of the dice

        //Loop to throw dice given number of times

        for( int numberOfRolls = 1; numberOfRolls < rolls; numberOfRolls++)

        {
              die1 = randNum.nextInt(6);
              die2 = randNum.nextInt(6);
              sumOfDice = die1 + die2;
              for( ; ; )
              {

            //Check if the sum of dice is equal to the given sum
                if(sumOfDice == 2)

                {
                    diceTotal2++;
                    probability2 = diceTotal2 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==3)
                {
                    diceTotal3++;
                    probability3 = diceTotal3 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==4)
                {
                    diceTotal4++;
                    probability4 = diceTotal4 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==5)
                {
                    diceTotal5++;
                    probability5 = diceTotal5 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==6)
                {
                    diceTotal6++;
                    probability6 = diceTotal6 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==7)
                {
                    diceTotal7++;
                    probability7 = diceTotal7 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==8)
                {
                    diceTotal8++;
                    probability8 = diceTotal8 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==9)
                {
                    diceTotal9++;
                    probability9 = diceTotal9 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==10)
                {
                    diceTotal10++;
                    probability10 = diceTotal10 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==11)
                {
                    diceTotal11++;
                    probability11 = diceTotal11 / numberOfRolls;
                }

                else if(sumOfDice ==12)
                {
                    diceTotal12++;
                    probability12 = diceTotal12 / numberOfRolls;
                }

            }                

        }



       System.out.println("Sum of Dice" + "         " + "Probability");
       System.out.println("2s: \t\t" + probability2 + "%");
       System.out.println("3s: \t\t" + probability3 + "%");
       System.out.println("4s: \t\t" + probability4 + "%");
       System.out.println("5s: \t\t" + probability5 + "%");
       System.out.println("6s: \t\t" + probability6 + "%");
       System.out.println("7s: \t\t" + probability7 + "%");
       System.out.println("8s: \t\t" + probability8 + "%");
       System.out.println("9s: \t\t" + probability9 + "%");
       System.out.println("10s: \t\t" + probability10 + "%");
       System.out.println("11s: \t\t" + probability11 + "%");
       System.out.println("12s: \t\t" + probability12 + "%");


        //After all throws, calculate percentage of throws that resulted in the given sum



} //end main
```

Comment: Note: your programmer would be a lot shorter and easier to read if you used arrays ...

Comment: I don't want to nit-pick, but the assignment sais `4. Calculate the probability of each combination of dice. [...]`. The number of throws does not influence this probability. What I think the assigner wants is `4. Simulate the throws and display the percentages of each possible sum. [...]`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have a solution, I would present you with another one:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nRolls = 100, nDice = 6; // default values

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number of throws: ");
        nRolls = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Number of sides on the dices: ");
        nDice = in.nextInt();

        int minSum = 2, maxSum = 2 * nDice;
        int[] hist = new int[maxSum - minSum + 1];

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int iter = 1; iter <= nRolls; iter++) {
            int throw1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(nDice), throw2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(nDice);
            int sum = throw1 + throw2;
            hist[sum - minSum]++;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of rolls: " + nRolls);
        System.out.println("Number of sides of the dice: " + nDice);
        System.out.println("Sum of Dice         Percentage");
        for (int i = 0; i < hist.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("   %2d                 %5.2f%%", i + minSum, hist[i] * 100.0 / nRolls));
            // System.out.println("   " + (i+minSum) + "             " + (hist[i]*100.0/nRolls);
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

It shows you how to use arrays to solve this task. Each entry in the array holds the number of throws that came up with the corresponding sum. You always have `2*nDice - 1` possible sums (you can not reach `1` with two dices), so the size of the array is dependent on the number of sides on the dice.

Then you just iterate through all throws and add 1 to the corresponding histogram entry (note that I offset the histogram, so `hist[0]` corresponds to a sum of 2, `hist[1]` to a sum of 3, etc).

At the end, you can just calculate the percentage. (It's not a probability, it's the percentage that this sum occured in our simulation. If you make the number of rolls larger, this percentage will be an approximation of the probability.)

At the end, you just print it out. The `String.format` stuff is just for alignment of the values. If you are confused about it, just use

```
System.out.println("   " + (i+minSum) + "             " + (hist[i]*100.0/nRolls);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change `numberOfRolls` initiation to 1 instead of 0.

```
for( int numberOfRolls = 1; numberOfRolls <= rolls; numberOfRolls++) {
```

If `numberOfRolls` is 0, all your division operations results in divide by ZERO.

```
probability2 = diceTotal2 / numberOfRolls;
```

Comment: Now when the user inputs a number of rolls, it doesnt except it. If I hit enter in my terminal after I have entered the number of rolls, it just goes to the next line and I can keep putting numbers in. It isn't moving forward in the program.

Comment: That is whole separate issue. I would suggest trim the code in your question to the line where you are having issue and post as new question.